# how to Share Data Count (Relationship in Coredata)

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have a question...

I have couple(2) of `ViewCotroller`.

name are `ViewController` and `DetailViewController`

`DetailViewController` has data(Relationship in Coredata).

this is `DetailViewController` code.

```
NSSet *tags = self.bookInfo.details.tags;
tagNamesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:tags.count];

for (Voca_Tag *tag in tags) {
    [tagNamesArray addObject:tag.mean];
}
```

I want using that `tagNamesArray.count` in `ViewController`.

also, I was used

```
DetailViewController *detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc]init];

[detailViewController.tageNamesArray count];
```

it didn't work.

I want use the Count to cell.text on UITableView.

pastebin.com/RwuR6PDt << ViewController 
pastebin.com/2F345vg7 << DetaulViewController

plz Check...

Answer (score 1):

You should write your delegate: In SecondViewController.H:

```
@protocol messageDelegate <NSObject>
@optional
-(void) sendDataCount:(NSInteger) i;
@end
@interface SecondViewController : NSString
@property (nonatomic, assign) id <messageDelegate> delegate;
@end
```

In SecondViewController.m:

```
-(void)readyToSend
{
    [self.delegate sendDataCount:__YOURCOUNT__];

}
```

In ViewController.h:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<messageDelegate>
@end
```

In ViewController.m: in

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
SecondViewController *secondViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
secondViewController.delegate = self;
}
-(void) sendDataCount:(NSInteger) i
{
    NSLog(@"Your Count  =  %d",i);
    //send Data using POST method
}
```

Hope it will help!

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work.
I want use the Count cell.text on UITableView

Comment: Check your step, it should work. For alternative you can use singleton.

Comment: In ViewController.h #include "SecondViewController.h"

Answer (score 0):

This is because tafNamesArray does not have memory allocation at that time and hence this array will returns nil and its count will be zero .

If you want to get [tafNamesArray count ] ,first call that method which initilize tafNamesArray, for example :

```
   In DetailViewController
    -(void)array
    {

    NSSet *tags = self.bookInfo.details.tags;
    tagNamesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:tags.count];

    for (Voca_Tag *tag in tags) {
        [tagNamesArray addObject:tag.mean];
    }
    }

    then In ViewController

    call :

    DetailViewController *detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc]init];
//First call this method
    [detailViewController array];
//then  this line will work
     int i =   [detailViewController.tafNamesArray count];
```